# Change script tag to clickable image

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have search everywhere on the net for an answer to this goal of mine.

```
<script class="custom"
   src="myscript.js"
   data-image="button.png"
   data-product="000452">
</script>
```

I would like the script tag to load myscript.js which will on-page-load transform the script tag itself to a clickable image using the data-image attribute value, then when clicked myscript.js will get the data-product value and forward the user to mywebsite.com/product/{value}

It sounds simple but I have so far failed to achieve this, also is it possible to get this done without jQuery or using a very small JS library?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why not just output the image directly?

Comment: Provide your http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sanjeev's below answer is what I am looking for, I am just wondering if its possible to get this done with javascript only or use a very light JS library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced the jquery script with image tag , Hope this work for you

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" class="custom" data-image="button.png" data-product="000452"></script>


            <script  type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){


              $('.custom').after('<a href ="http://mywebsite.com/product/'+$('.custom').attr('data-product')+'"><img src='+$('.custom').attr('data-image')+' /></a>' ); //add img tag after script tag


               $('.custom').remove(); //remove the script tag
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: This works PERFECTLY, one last thing, is there a way to get this done without jquery or use a very light JS library?

Comment: Don't worry, I am ok with this.